# jQuery UI.Layout: How to delay pane opening

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-layout

I am using UI.Layout, trying to create a behavior similar to the ExtJs layout: On close / open of the horizontal panes, the resizer should be hidden and re-appear with a slide effect.

This was easy on pane closing, since the effect appears after the `onclose` event,  but I'm having serious difficulties on applying the same behavior on pane open.

Since the event for `onopen` triggers regardless of the effect being applied on the resizer, i find no way of delaying the pane opening until the resizer slide is complete.

Here is the relevant code:

```js
outerLayout = $('#outer-layout').layout({
    west : {
        // ...
        onclose_start : function() {
            hideResizer('west');
        },
        onclose_end : function() {
            styleResizer('west');
            showResizer('west');
            animateResizerOnClose('west');
        },
        onopen_start : animateWestResizerOnOpen
    }
    // ...
});

function animateWestResizerOnOpen() {
    $(this).parent().delay(1400).queue(function() {
        $('#outer-layout').layout().open('west');
    }).hide('slide', 300);
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat of a workaround, but it works well:

Since it seems there is no way of interfering with the fx-queue of the pane-resizer, and `setTimeout()` would offer no help, having the event triggering regardless, I sidesteped the problem using a steeper curve of the pane opening fx easing. This allows for the pane to open with a relativly slow start, and the resizer back-slide shows.